# Can the Croatian ‘future II’ be understood as a conditional future?

Tags: bosnian-croatian-serbian, future

While reading [*Futur drugi u suvremenom hrvatskom jeziku. P Vuković. Jezik: časopis za kulturu hrvatskoga književnog jezika*](https://hrcak.srce.hr/file/197114) about the so-called ‘future II’ in modern Croatian, I came across this section:

> Pogodba koju izriče rečenica s futurom prvim pritom ima vrlo specifičnu narav – uvjet za radnju glavne surečenice nije, naime, sâmo izvođenje radnje zavisne surečenice, nego postojanje sigurnosti ili barem mogućnosti da će ta radnja biti izvedena nakon
> izvođenja radnje glavne surečenice, npr.
>
> > *Uzmi moj život ako će ti to pomoći;
> >
> > Ne žele podržati njihovu smjenu ako će na njihova mjesta doći Pašalićevi ljudi;
> >
> > Ne moramo pobijediti nikoga u pripremnom razdoblju ako ćemo biti dobri u Portugalu*.

– which roughly translates as:

> The agreement expressed by the sentence with the future first has a very specific nature - the condition for the action of the main clause is not, namely, the execution of the action of the dependent clause, but the existence of certainty or at least the possibility that this action will be performed after the execution of the action of the main clause, e.g.
>
> > *Take my life if it will help you;
> >
> > They do not want to support their dismissal if Pašalić's men will take their place;
> >
> > We don't have to beat anyone in the pre-season if we're going to do well in Portugal.*

I was wondering if I’ve understood future II correctly.

In short, when we have a possibility-condition and a possible-consequence, both in the future, we use future II (*futur drugi*) for the former and future I (*futur prvi*) for the latter, as in "Take my life, if this would help" above.

Is this a correct understanding of future II? Are there any counter-examples? Like this one:

> Morat ćeš pojesti još puno žganaca prije nego što budeš mogao otvoriti instalacije.

– in which the condition and the sequence seem reversed, but it feels right anyway, even with this inside-out logic.